# Where are the missing pages?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Im in the 100-acre woods and was told I had to find missing pages. Im stuck because I have looked all around the book and can find a single thing! Is there anything im missing, or something like that, because im clueless. I AM COMPLETELY LOST!! This is my first time playing kh1 so it's even worse lol. Anyways, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Traverse Town: Rescue 51 Dalmatians.

Agrabah: Dark Chamber in the Cave of Wonders.

Monstro: Chamber 6.

Halloweentown: The bookcase in the Doctor's Lab.

Atlantica: Ariel's Grotto.

Note that you can find the pages in any order -- the sections of the Wood are unlocked in the same order regardless of which pages you bring back when.